How can I qualify an ambiguous type when a library has a type of the same name, and I'm re-exporting imported libraries?
My library imports and re-exports JSONRPC, JSONSchema and JSONSchemaBuilder. JSONRPC, JSONSchema both define a different JSONValue type.
The JSONSchemaBuilder library has a type named JSONSchema, like the other library.
I would like to refer to JSONSchema.JSONValue. How can I do this?
// MyLibrary.exports.swift
@_exported import JSONRPC
@_exported import JSONSchema
@_exported import JSONSchemaBuilder

// MyLibrary.code.swift
import JSONSchema

let foo: JSONValue // -> 'JSONValue' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context
let bar: JSONSchema.JSONValue // 'JSONValue' is not a member type of generic struct 'JSONSchemaBuilder.JSONSchema'

The first error definitively makes sense. The second one is more mysterious. The compiler thinks I'm referring to JSONSchema.JSONValue from JSONSchemaBuilder instead of JSONValue from JSONSchema. This doesn't seem to be the right evaluation priority as one always has the option to write JSONSchemaBuilder.JSONSchema.JSONValue to refer to the first option.
Because I'm re-exporting those libraries, I don't think I have the option to create a file that only imports from the desired library and adds a typealias.
The two options I can see are:

drop the re-exports. I think this would hurt a bit the experience interacting with the end product but is acceptable.
create another module, that only imports from JSONSchema and define a typealias there. I don't like the idea of having a module for a single typealias.


have you tried using MyLibrary.JSONSchema. ...,
whenever you want to refer to your library

I want to refer to types outside of my library. I think my issue boils down to not being able to refers to the JSONSchema library when there also a type named JSONSchema in scope.

have you tried using Swift.JSONSchema. ...
